# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. Shopping cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a simple shopping cart with JS.

```
$('.addToCart').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  var price = Number($(this).data('price'));
  cart.addProduct(name, price, 1);
});
```

and here is my cart object

```
var cart = (function () {
  cartStorage = [];

  function Product(name, price, count) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.count = count;
  }
  var object = {};
  object.addProduct = function (name, price, count) {
    for (var i in cartStorage) {
      if (cartStorage[i].name == object.name) {
        cartStorage[i].count++;
        return;
      }
    }
    var newItem = Product(name, price, count);
    console.log(newItem);
    cartStorage.push(newItem);
  }
```

It prints *undefined* when I'am trying to console log it. And if I click one more time on a button it says 'Cannot read property 'name'.

here is my typical item card block

```
            <div class="col-8 col-md-4 col-lg-3 card">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=9">
                <div class="priceWrapper">
                    <input type="button" value="BUY" class = "addToCart" data-name = "Product #8" data-price = "0.001">
                    <p class="newPrice">0.001$ </p>
                    <p class="oldPrice"><strike>300$</strike></p>
                </div>
                <p class="item-name">Product #8 </p>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your obect is null and it is being not assigned by a product object, thats why it gave you an undefind error.

Comment: @MaheshS how do I fix that? It should be passed to the method

Comment: Just add object = new Product(name, price, count); at the first line of the funciton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var newItem = new Product(name, price, count);
```

Use keyword `new` for new object from object constructor function.

Answer (score 0):

you're doing this: `var object = {}`, and a few lines later, this: `object.name`.

Of course you'll get an error... I do not know what you were trying to do, but you have to initialize that object first to access any properties on it...

And as a side not, naming a variable "object" is not a really good idea, try to give your variables more meaningful names. It would make your code more readable both to you and to other developers coming after you.

Comment: But I will listen to your advice

Comment: @LordNani you got pretty far in 2 hours lol. If its just for study it won't matter much, but its good to practice those things even when you not writing for others so you get used to it :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code can give you some hints...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="col-8 col-md-4 col-lg-3 card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=9">
    <div class="priceWrapper">
      <input type="button" value="BUY" class="addToCart" data-name="Product #8" data-price="0.001">
      <p class="newPrice">0.001$ </p>
      <p class="oldPrice">
        <strike>3$</strike>
      </p>
    </div>
    <p class="item-name">Product #8 </p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-8 col-md-4 col-lg-3 card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?random=9">
    <div class="priceWrapper">
      <input type="button" value="BUY" class="addToCart" data-name="Product #9" data-price="0.002">
      <p class="newPrice">0.002$ </p>
      <p class="oldPrice">
        <strike>2$</strike>
      </p>
    </div>
    <p class="item-name">Product #8 </p>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var cart = (function () {

      const cartStorage = [];
      function Product(name, price, count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.count = count;
      }
      var object = {};
      object.addProduct = function (name, price, count) {
        var isProductAlredyInCart = false
        for (var i in cartStorage) {
          if (cartStorage[i].name == name) {
            cartStorage[i].count++;
            isProductAlredyInCart = true;
          }
        }
        if (!isProductAlredyInCart) {
          var newItem = new Product(name, price, count);
          cartStorage.push(newItem);
        }
        console.log(cartStorage);
      }
      return object;
    })();

    $('.addToCart').click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var name = $(this).data('name');
      var price = Number($(this).data('price'));
      cart.addProduct(name, price, 1);
    });

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

You need to return object from the cart function, suggestion from @Huỳnh Tuân is perfect.

I would personally suggest first you sharp your JS basics, like how `new` works ?, closures etc.